# Unable to read the data from channels (Thing Speak)

Tags: java

I created channels through Thingspeak and I am able to write the values into channel through Java program but not able to read the data from channels....my intention is create a new file and read all the values into that particular file....please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give some code snippet, which you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to write "hello" to field1 of ThingSpeak public channel 1234.

```
String apiWriteKey = "your-channel-write-key";
Channel channel = new Channel(1234, apiWriteKey);

Entry entry = new Entry();
entry.setField(1, "hello");
channel.update(entry);
```

And here is how to read it back:

```
Channel channel = new Channel(1234);
Entry entry = channel.getLastChannelEntry();
System.out.println(entry.getField(1);
```

Source : https://github.com/angryelectron/thingspeak-java/

Hope this will help you :)